# ExtJS 4 - implementing the User Extensions/Plug in of others?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am creating a web application and I planned on implementing a password strength meter in it. There are a lot of examples [such as this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?168452-Ext.ux.form.PasswordMeter), however, I am having a difficult time implementing the solution on my own using Sencha Architect. I am trying to implement [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/rgralhoz/f8xUz/75/) of the solution.

So far, I've added the password meter code into my resources folder as such:

This is the `Ext.ux.form.field.PasswordMeter.js` file located at my `resources/scripts` folder.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.field.PasswordMeter', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',
    alias: 'widget.ux.passwordmeterfield',
    inputType: 'password',

    reset: function() {
        this.callParent();
        this.updateMeter();
    },

    fieldSubTpl: [
        '<div><input id="{id}" type="{type}" ',
        '<tpl if="name">name="{name}" </tpl>',
        '<tpl if="fieldStyle"> style="{fieldStyle}"</tpl>',
        '<tpl if="size">size="{size}" </tpl>',
        '<tpl if="tabIdx">tabIndex="{tabIdx}" </tpl>',
        'class="{fieldCls} {typeCls}" autocomplete="off" /></div>',
        '<div class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'form-strengthmeter">',
        '<div class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'form-strengthmeter-scorebar">&nbsp;</div>',
        '</div>',
        {
            compiled: true,
            disableFormats: true
        }
    ],

    // private
    onChange: function(newValue, oldValue) {
        this.updateMeter(newValue);
    },
    
    /**
     * Sets the width of the meter, based on the score
     * 
     * @param {Object} e Private function
     */
    updateMeter : function(val) {
        var me = this, maxWidth, score, scoreWidth,
            objMeter = me.el.down('.' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'form-strengthmeter'),
            scoreBar = me.el.down('.' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'form-strengthmeter-scorebar');

        if (val){
            maxWidth = objMeter.getWidth();
            score = me.calcStrength(val);
            scoreWidth = maxWidth - (maxWidth / 100) * score;
            scoreBar.setWidth(scoreWidth, true);
        } else {
            scoreBar.setWidth('100%');
        }
    },

    /**
     * Calculates the strength of a password
     * 
     * @param {Object} p The password that needs to be calculated
     * @return {int} intScore The strength score of the password
     */
    calcStrength: function(p) {
        // PASSWORD LENGTH
        var len = p.length,
            score = len;

        if (len > 0 && len <= 4) { // length 4 or
            // less
            score += len
        } else if (len >= 5 && len <= 7) {
            // length between 5 and 7
            score += 6;
        } else if (len >= 8 && len <= 15) {
            // length between 8 and 15
            score += 12;
        } else if (len >= 16) { // length 16 or more
            score += 18;
        }

        // LETTERS (Not exactly implemented as dictacted above
        // because of my limited understanding of Regex)
        if (p.match(/[a-z]/)) {
            // [verified] at least one lower case letter
            score += 1;
        }
        if (p.match(/[A-Z]/)) { // [verified] at least one upper
            // case letter
            score += 5;
        }
        // NUMBERS
        if (p.match(/\d/)) { // [verified] at least one
            // number
            score += 5;
        }
        if (p.match(/(?:.*?\d){3}/)) {
            // [verified] at least three numbers
            score += 5;
        }

        // SPECIAL CHAR
        if (p.match(/[\!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,\*,\?,_,~]/)) {
            // [verified] at least one special character
            score += 5;
        }
        // [verified] at least two special characters
        if (p.match(/(?:.*?[\!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,\*,\?,_,~]){2}/)) {
            score += 5;
        }

        // COMBOS
        if (p.match(/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/)) {
            // [verified] both upper and lower case
            score += 2;
        }
        if (p.match(/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/)) {
            // [verified] both letters and numbers
            score += 2;
        }
        // [verified] letters, numbers, and special characters
        if (p.match(/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,\*,\?,_,~])/)) {
            score += 2;
        }

        return Math.min(Math.round(score * 2), 100);
    }
});
```

However, I'm having a tough time wondering how to implement the latter part:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var win = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        frame: true,
        title: 'Simple Form',
        bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
        width: 400,
        margin: 20,

        items: [{
            xtype: 'ux.passwordmeterfield',
            labelAlign: 'left',
            fieldLabel: 'Password',
            name: 'foo',
            anchor: '100%',
            margin: '0 0 20 0',
        }]
    });

    win.render(document.body);
});
```

I know the crucial part is adding the `items` block. However, in Sencha Architect, I can't just input values in the code pat of my view. I also can't add the `xtype` value as it is reserved.

How can I add user extensions/plugins properly using Sencha Architect?

PS. As much as possible, I don't want to go as far as making it to a user extension (.aux) file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, although that you do not want to make it into an .aux, that it the proper way how to add an extension to Architect.

Making an aux is not very difficult as it boils down to adding required a configuration variables to `package.json`, zip it (and change extension to .aux) and adding it to Architect.

The whole process is explained in [Creating User Extensions](http://docs.sencha.com/architect/3/extending_architect/creating_user_extensions.html). Another very helpful article is [User Extension Structure](http://docs.sencha.com/architect/3/reference/user_extension_structure.html) because it describes what you need to add to package.json (and possibly to other files) for Architect to accept the resulting package (.aux).